# Download song data then play from file

Tags: swift

I am trying to download Data from a song link, save it to a file, and then play from the file. Breakpoint is not going on catch block but I don't hear the music. What's wrong with my code?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let url = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"
    downloadSong(url: url)
}

func downloadSong(url: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.savedFiles[url.absoluteString] = data
                self.playAudio(fromData: data, url: url)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}

func playAudio(fromData audioData: Data, url: URL) {
    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let audioFileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    
    do {
        try audioData.write(to: audioFileURL)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let audioPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioFileURL)
            let audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: audioPlayerItem)
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error writing audio data to file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

```
<key>NSFileProviderExtension</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSFileProviderWritable</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I set this entitlement.

Comment: `let audioPlayer =` is a local var, could the be issue. Also, you might want to listen to errors of the `AVPlayer`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback/observing_playback_state and `prepareToPlay()` might be needed too.

Comment: @Larme is right, you need to create a global variable `private var audioPlayer: AVPlayer?` and use that one instead of a local one.
`audioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: audioPlayerItem)`
`audioPlayer?.play()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AVPlayer as your view controller class variable. In your code player deinits after DispatchQueue block finishes

```swift
let audioPlayer = AVPlayer()
func playAudio(fromData audioData: Data, url: URL) {
    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let audioFileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    
    do {
        try audioData.write(to: audioFileURL)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak audioPlayer] in
            let audioPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioFileURL)
            audioPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: audioPlayerItem)
            audioPlayer?.play()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error writing audio data to file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```